# How to make a side panel in a component with Quasar Vue Framework 14.3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, quasar-framework

I have a working left side panel using Quasar version 14.3. Now I want to make it a component. When I use this:

```
<template>
  <q-layout ref="layout"
            :left-breakpoint=0>

    <q-scroll-area slot="left" style="width: 80%; height: 100%>
      <div>
        <left-panel></left-panel>
      </div>
    </q-scroll-area>
  </q-layout>
</template>
```

It kind of works, however:

- the width gives css issues
- do I really have to keep the q-scroll-area out of the component? When
  I include it the side panel does not hide but is in the page and then
  the actual page is below it when you scroll down.

Any suggestion to how to make a solid side panel in a component with Quasar?

Comment: I not sure if what you want is a drawer, I have some problems to start with quasar, and searching help see that there exists a quasar admin panel example that have the drawer and toolbar in components, not sure if that can help you... https://github.com/odranoelBR/vue-quasar-admin-example/tree/master/src/components/layout/drawer

Comment: @FabianSilva Thanks for the very nice example. I like it a lot. I looked into it carefully since there is a lot to be learned from it. However for my issue it is relevant that it use version 13 of Quasar, whereas I am on v14. In v14 the drawer was implemented differently, see here: http://quasar-framework.org/components/layout.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use q-layout-drawer for creating the left panel in q-layout

```html
<template>
  <q-layout ref="layout" :left-breakpoint=0>
    <q-layout-drawer v-model="flag" side="left">
      <q-scroll-area slot="left" style="width: 80%; height: 100%">
        <div>
          <left-panel></left-panel>
        </div>
      </q-scroll-area>
    </q-layout-drawer>
  </q-layout>
</template>
```

Set flag true in data of Vue component.You can also open/close drawer on button click by setting flag true false